How to add SD driver on KC-705 from Xilinx in Vivado BD
When I trying to add ip core for sd card in vivado block design, it write errors while generating bitstream.
Errors is "Unspecified I/O Standard" and "Unconstrained Logical Port" for ports sd_clk sd_dat_i sd_dat_o sd_dat_t sd_cmd_i sd_cmd_o sd_cmd_t sd_int
Where I can find what I/O Standard I should use for these ports?


Where I can find what I/O Standard I should use for these ports?

See figure 1-7 in the KC 705 user guide
It looks like this:

The pin number and I/O standard are configured and read by Vivado using a constraints file.  The constraints file is added to the Vivado project or read in as add constraints <file> in a non-project mode (tcl script based) work flow.  Its an *.xdc format file.  You can find it for this hardware platform by searching 'KC 705 constraints file'.  Here is a good place to look Xilinx Support.
The schematic names in table 1-7 don't perfectly match the names in your post.  There must be a mapping between the two sets of names, probably depends on a particular configuration. You will need to research this for you application.
Take care to verify the version of the documentation against the version of the board you have.
According to this user guide, the standard for all the SD card interface I/O is LVCMOS25.
